# XAML Command binding from parent class

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

In my ViewModel i Have base Card class and Deck class which contain Observable Collection of Cards. Here is how it is bound in XAML

```
        <GridView.DataContext>
             <local:Deck/>
        </GridView.DataContext>
        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding DeckCollection}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=??}"
                            CommandParameter=??
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image 
                                    Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                    Stretch="None"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Tried to use RelativeSource but that gave me 6 errors.

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Deck}, Path=ActionCommand}}">
```

The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.

The property 'Path' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.

The member "AncestorType" is not recognized or is not accessible.

The member "Path" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Unknown member 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'

Unknown member 'Path' on element 'RelativeSource'

Here are my classes

```
class Deck
{
    private ObservableCollection<Card> _deckCollection = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    public ObservableCollection<Card> DeckCollection
    {
        get { return _deckCollection; }
        set { _deckCollection = value; }
    }

    public Deck()
    {
        ActionCommand = new MyCommand();
        ActionCommand.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
        ActionCommand.ExecuteFunc = AddToList;
    }


    public void AddToList(object parameter)
    {
       //add Card to list which in this case is not possible
       DeckCollection.Add(this) ?
    }
}

class Card
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public String ImagePath { get; set; }
    public MyCommand ActionCommand { get; set; }
}
```

And also MyCommand class

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{

    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteFunc { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: If this is WinRT XAML, then no, there is no `RelativeSource`. You will need a lot of horrible code-behind hacks, because it's 1990 and we're doing COM stuff.

Comment: Is there any other way to bind this and have acces to DeckCollection through command or button click?

Comment: Well, I can think of putting the command inside `Card`, but that's horrible too.

Comment: If you use MvvmLight you can do, Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.SelectMarker}"